# SQL query Help with OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, outer-join

I have two tables like this.

Table1

```
Column   |       Type       |
---------+------------------+
 cod     | text             |
 value99 | double precision |
```

Table2

```
Column   |       Type       |
---------+------------------+
 cod     | text             |
 value06 | double precision |
```

and i'd like to join them so i'd have something like

```
Column   |       Type       |
---------+------------------+
 cod     | text             |
 value99 | double precision |
 value06 | double precision |
```

the problem is that not all the codes are present in both tables, so if a code is not present in one of the tables it's value should be null.. In the end i'd like something like this

```
cod      |      value99     |      value06     |
---------+------------------+------------------+
 1       |     10           |       20         |
 2       |     13           |      NULL        |
 3       |     NULL         |        15        |
```

I think that its not possible using LEFT or RIGHT JOIN.. or maybe it is... any ideas? Thx=)

EDITED:
I've tried the FULL OUTER JOIN but the result is something like

```
code    value  code    value
1       10     1    4
2    15     NULL    NULL
NULL NULL 3 36
```

ANSWER!!!:
i found the answer thx to @Tobiasopdenbrouw :

```
SELECT test1.code,test1.value,test2.value FROM public.test1 LEFT OUTER JOIN public.test2 ON test1.code=test2.code
UNION
SELECT test2.code,test1.value,test2.value FROM public.test1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN public.test2 ON test1.code=test2.code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit, because your question doesn't describe the required output in great detail, but what you probably need is a helper query that will create a table with all the codes for you (a `UNION` of 2 `SELECT` querys). This helper table can then be `LEFT JOINED` to your 2 source tables).

Edit: I thought of the (FULL) OUTER JOIN answer myself, but in reading between the lines, I don't think that's what the OP really needs. But I can be wrong, of course.

Comment: i'd rather not use a table with all the codes. But it seems that the full outer join is the answer, but the output gives me the "code" in two columns

Comment: have you looked into kristof's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx).

> **Using Full Outer Joins**
>
> To retain the
>   nonmatching information by including
>   nonmatching rows in the results of a
>   join, use a full outer join. SQL
>   Server provides the full outer join
>   operator, FULL OUTER JOIN, which
>   includes all rows from both tables,
>   regardless of whether or not the other
>   table has a matching value.
>
> Consider a join of the Product table
>   and the SalesOrderDetail table on
>   their ProductID columns. The results
>   show only the Products that have sales
>   orders on them. The ISO FULL OUTER
>   JOIN operator indicates that all rows
>   from both tables are to be included in
>   the results, regardless of whether
>   there is matching data in the tables.
>
> You can include a WHERE clause with a
>   full outer join to return only the
>   rows where there is no matching data
>   between the tables. The following
>   query returns only those products that
>   have no matching sales orders, as well
>   as those sales orders that are not
>   matched to a product (although all
>   sales orders, in this case, are
>   matched to a product).

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.cod, t2.cod)
    ,t1.value99
    ,t2.value06
from 
    table1 t1 
    full outer join table2 t2 on t1.cod= t2.cod
```